# Passenger PassengerAgent does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger, capistrano3

I'm updating the passenger for my app with rvm. Afterwards I used `passenger-config --root` to find the passenger and added it to my nginx.conf. This is the directory:

```
shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30
```

I'm not sure why the passenger root is this one. I thought it'll be the one installed under .rvm. Anyway, I got this error:

```
Unable to start Phusion Passenger: Support binary PassengerAgent not found...
```

I am able to use back my previous passenger, and I noticed the difference is the new package has no `buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent`. Am I missing something here?

Setup:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
rvm 1.29.3
rails 4.2.10
ruby 2.3
capistrano 3
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I installed passenger with rvm. So I need to follow the instructions [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_rvm/) and run `passenger-install-nginx-module` to do it correctly.